# How to Rename a Logged Parameter in mlflow without Losing Historical Data

Tags: mlflow

I'm working with the `mlflow` library in Python to log parameters from my code. Recently, I decided to rename one of the parameters. However, my issue is that I'm still logging with the old parameter name in `mlflow`.

This is how I currently log the parameter:

```py
mlflow.log_param("old_param_name", new_variable_name)
```

And I want to change it to:

```py
mlflow.log_param("new_param_name", new_variable_name)
```

However, I want the historical logs which used `'old_param_name'` to show `'new_param_name'`. I believe that the logs are stored in a database.

1. Is there a way in `mlflow` to rename a logged parameter so that the historical values already logged appear with the new parameter name?
2. If the logs are stored in a database, is it possible to directly alter the column name for this parameter?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no convenient way to do it. The only thing that you can do by Mlflow is to log a new param against the old run by using `mlflow.client` which is described [here](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.client.html#mlflow.client.MlflowClient.log_param).

---

As you mentioned, you can rename the param by altering the column name in the database. Clearly, you can do this only if your tracking server is a database.

If you store your runs in a local file path, you need to only change file names in the `params` directory for each run.